# It won't allow me to create an outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I've got a Table View Controller object in my Storyboard, but I've made it a custom class called StaticDetailViewController, which I created as a subclass of UITableViewController.

However, when I go to drag from the view to the .h file in the Assistant view, no connection option appears. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe you have the assistant specified to the wrong file. Press the 'x' button, close assistant and then reopen it and it should open to the right file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open and close your curly braces for your @interface in the .h file. For some reason it won't let you control drag using the assistant editor unless you do so... (screenshot)

[image]