# Xcode 4 control-drag won't create first IBOutlet or IBAction if '@end' is a header file's last line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ibaction, iboutlet

I created an Xcode 4.5.2 project starting with the Single View Application for iPhone template. After adding a UIButton to MainStoryboard.storyboard, I'm able to control-drag from the button to ViewController.h's code to create a new IBOutlet or IBAction.
[image: with extra line]

However, if I remove the last line following `@end`, which is empty, control-dragging does not offer to create an IBOutlet or IBAction.
[image: without extra line]

If I add a property to ViewController, then control-dragging offers to create IBOutlets and IBActions again.
[image: existing property]

*Edit 1*: As [jhilgert00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126783/jhilgert00) pointed out, adding curly braces, as if to create a place to declare instance variables, causes Xcode to once again offer to create IBOutlets and IBActions.

Is this an Xcode bug? Or should I not trim the empty line after `@end`?

*Edit 2*: This issue has been fixed in Xcode 5.

Comment: I had no idea one could do this at all; I have always created my `IBOutlet`s in the interface file first.

Comment: thats a cool feature did not know that either. looks definitely like a bug to me. its perfectly valid to have no empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: Got the same problem. Most be a bug because I am able to reproduce it at will just by deleting and inserting that empty last line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer would be that this is a bug that should be filed at https://bugreport.apple.com, I doubt anyone here can give a useful answer. That said it's always a good idea to leave whitespace at the end of a file!

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to get confirmation that the problem isn't localized to me, and I hope others find this question if they Google the problem before Apple can fix it. I'll submit a bug report to Apple shortly.

Comment: Why would you recommend leaving whitespace at the end of a file?

Comment: There's a good discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline). Long story short: some programs have problems parsing files without a newline as the last character, not to mention the C standard dictates that should be the case.

Answer (score 4):

It seems stupid, but opening and closing your curly braces for your `@interface` seems to fix this issue.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : View Controller {

// Drag your IBOutlets here...

}

@end
```

Screenshot on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831921/1126783).

Comment: True. Adding curly brackets, as if to create a place to declare instance variables, causes Xcode to once again offer to create IBOutlets and IBActions. However, my question is not "how can I fix this?", but "should Xcode be doing this in the first place?". Others seem to agree that it's an Xcode bug, so I'll likely submit it to Apple soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, this happened to me because I had not changed my ViewController from generic one to the one I was trying to drag to, which makes sense.